# How to run grunt-phantomas for multiple pages

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, phantomjs

How to run grunt-phantomas for multiple pages?
Presently I am able to pass a single URL in this grunt task grunt-phantomas, I tried googling but haven't found any support to pass multiple pages.

Presently I am using

`phantomas: {
            prod: {
                options: {
                    indexPath: './public/phantomas/',
                    options: {
                        'timeout': 30
                    },
                    url: 'http://www.homesofa.de/',
                    buildUi: true
                }
            }
        }`

I am looking for something like:

```
phantomas: {
        prod: {
            options: {
                indexPath: './public/phantomas/',
                options: {
                    'timeout': 30
                },
                urls: [
                  'http://www.google.com',
                  'http://www.yahoo.com',
                  'http://www.github.com',
                  'http://www.facebook.com'
                  ],
                buildUi: true
            }
        }
    }
```